# How to handle inexistent resources using react query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm making a protected route system that only allows user with the given role or higher to access certain pages. I made the backend in flask and the route to get the information looks like this

```
@auth.route("/users/<string:token>")
def getUser(token):
    user = User.query.filter_by(token=token).first()

    if not user:
        return "user not found", 404

    return {"username": user.username, "role": user.role}
```

This function takes a token that should be stored in the user's cookies if it has previously logged in. Then I have a function in JavaScript that calls this route and handles the response

```
function useUser() {
    //This returns undefined if user hasn't previously logged in
    const token = cookies.get("token");

    return useQuery("user", async() => {
        const res = await axios.get(`auth/users/${token}`)
        .catch(/* Not sure what to catch here */);
        return res.data;
    });
}
```

And finally I have the actual protected route

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({path, accessibleBy, redirectTo, children}) => {
    const {user, status} = useUser();

    if (user === undefined || (user.role !== roles.ADMIN && accessibleBy === roles.ADMIN)) {
        return(<Redirect to={redirectTo}/>)
    };

    return (
        <Route path={path}>
            {children}
        </Route>
    )
}
```

This kind of works. There's a few bugs I still need to fix but I feel there has to be a better and more straight forward way of handling this. Am I right or is the way I'm doing it the intended way?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

- don't catch inside the `queryFn`. Just let the promise fail and give it to react-query, so that it can perform error handling, potentially retrying and then give you the error in the `error` field returned from `useQuery`.
- move the cookie reading either *inside* the queryFn or add it to the queryKey so that it becomes a real dependency, otherwise, you might risk stale closure problems. I would just move it inside the queryFn tbh. You can also instantly reject the Promise if the cookie is not there if that fits your use-case.
- I would use the `onError` callback to perform redirects, but it looks like you want to also redirect some legit users where the promise won't fail? Just keep in mind that `user` will be `undefined` while the promise is still pending, so with the above code, I think you would redirect the user too early.